# Peer to Peer Cuda Kernels - OpenGL Interop

Tags: opengl, interop, cuda, p2p

I have 2 devices (geforce 680s) with peer to peer access enabled and verified between them. However, I am unable to edit a buffer on "device 0" from "device 1". This is my code:

```
// map 2 pixel buffer objects to primary device
uchar4* dev0_buffer0=NULL;
uchar4* dev0_buffer1=NULL;
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)&dev0_buffer0, m_pbo0);
cudaGLMapBufferObject((void**)&dev0_buffer1, m_pbo1);
kernel<<< nBlocks, nThreads>>>(dev0_buffer0, width, height);

// write to a pbo on device 0 using device 1
cudaSetDevice(1);
kernel<<< nBlocks, nThreads>>>(dev0_buffer1, width, height);
```

Device 0 can write to both buffers mapped to it, but if I try to write to one of the buffers using Device 1 (like in the code above), nothing happens. No errors or crashes, it just doesn't affect the buffer (which I am rendering to screen to check)

Is this not possible?

Comment: Did you try to use GPUDirect ?

Comment: @marina.k: obviously they did - peer to peer access **is** GPUDirect.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have a suspicion it won't work. It probably requires OpenGL context sharing for this to work properly, and in the "old days" that meant using `WGL_NV_gpu_affinity` which was only supported on Quadro cards. CUDA OpenGL buffer mapping won't be registering the address into the unified address model and `cudaSetDevice` won't also change OpenGL contexts, and I am guessing that is where the problem comes from. You should also use `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer` for this, `cudaGLMapBufferObject` is deprecated.